# How to call a Stored procedure with aggregate result in output?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, aggregate, sys-refcursor

I have a simple select query that needs to be put into a stored procedure.
The query takes in 3 parameters and displays 2 columns as result, one of them being an aggregate.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "B_SP_GET_TOTAL_CLOCKED_IN_TIME"
(
     cv_1 IN OUT TYPES.cursorType,
     p_PARENT_CLIENT_ID IN NUMBER DEFAULT 10000,
     p_START_TIME IN NVARCHAR2,
     p_END_TIME IN NVARCHAR2
)
AS
v_sql VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
v_sql := 'SELECT b.CLIENT_NAME, ROUND(SUM((a.ENDTIME-a.STARTTIME)*24*60),2) TOTAL_CLOCKIN_TIME
      FROM TIMESHEET a
      INNER JOIN CLIENTS b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID
      INNER JOIN CLOCKACTIONS c ON c.ID = a.CLOCKACTIONID
      WHERE a.STARTTIME > p_START_TIME AND a.ENDTIME < p_END_TIME AND b.PARENT_CLIENT_ID = p_PARENT_CLIENT_ID 
      GROUP BY b.CLIENT_NAME';    
    OPEN cv_1 FOR v_sql;
END;
```

I executed the stored procedure and it got compiled, with no issues. 
How do i check if its working properly? As in how do I test it now?

The statement I used to test the above procedure can be found below:

```
execute B_SP_GET_TOTAL_CLOCKED_IN_TIME(10000,'04-01-2015 00:00:00','05-01-2015 00:00:00');
```

This was the error I got:

```
 Error starting at line : 1 in command - execute B_SP_GET_TOTAL_CLOCKED_IN_TIME(10000,'04-01-2015 00:00:00','05-01-2015 00:00:00') 
Error report - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: 
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'B_SP_GET_TOTAL_CLOCKED_IN_TIME' 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Comment: `p_START_TIME` is a parameter, but you have hardcoded it in the string. Build it dynamically using concatenation operator `||`.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Agree with @Sathya, in fact you don't need dynamic sql here. Use OPEN FOR SELECT and pass the parameter, in PL/SQL it will be referred as bind variable itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not need of (ab)using **dynamic SQL**. You could simple use `OPEN FOR SELECT` and use a **SYS_REFCURSOR**.

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE p_get_emp(
  3      p_deptno IN emp.deptno%TYPE,
  4      p_ref OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
  5  AS
  6  BEGIN
  7    OPEN   p_ref FOR
  8    SELECT ename,
  9           empno,
 10           deptno
 11    FROM   emp
 12    WHERE  deptno = p_deptno
 13    ORDER BY empno;
 14  END p_get_emp;
 15  /

Procedure created.

SQL>
SQL> sho err
No errors.
SQL>
```

Procedure created without any errors. Let's test it:

```
SQL> var p_ref refcursor
SQL>
SQL> EXEC p_get_emp  (30, :p_ref);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
SQL> print p_ref

ENAME           EMPNO     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- ----------
ALLEN            7499         30
WARD             7521         30
MARTIN           7654         30
BLAKE            7698         30
TURNER           7844         30
JAMES            7900         30

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```